# How to access the value of the Label present inside Datagrid asp.net using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datagrid

```
 <asp:DataGrid ID="datagrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
                    DataKeyField="Expr1" OnItemCommand="datagrid1_ItemCommand" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" 
                    >
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#2E882E" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                         <td class="style1">
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
  </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:DataGrid>
```

How can i access this Status Label value using `jquery` Please help

```
   var DataGrid1 = $("<%=datagrid1.ClientID %>");
var status = $(DataGrid1).children("lblStatus").get(0).innerHTML;
```

Will the above code work?

EDIT : Tried using this code as suggested

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.vini').click(function () {
            //var status = $("#<%=ddlstatus.ClientID%>").val();
            var DataGrid1 = $("#<%=datagrid1.ClientID %>");
              var status =$(DataGrid1).find("txtStatDesc").html();




            if (status == 'Sent') {
                var _Action = confirm('Do you really want to cancel this payment ? All pending money will be available in the retention account of the contractor ');
                if (_Action) {
                    $.blockUI({ css: {
                        border: 'none',
                        padding: '15px',
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                        '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                        opacity: .5,
                        color: '#fff'
                    }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }


            }

        });
    });
```

**I am not able to fetch the status but**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it will not work. becoz `label` is not direct child of `datagrid1`.
you can use like this

```
 var DataGrid1 = $("<%=datagrid1.ClientID %>");
 $("#"+DataGrid1).find("label").html();
```

please refer about children api in jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Your code also won't work as you missed sharp symbol in grid selector `$("#<%=datagrid1.ClientID %>")`

Comment: could you provide a link for the selector?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy:can you please tell me what is the problem in my selector?

Comment: @YogeshWaran, please refer about id selector in jquery ;) : http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: where should i put this code in cause i have to call this in cancel button click which is present inside my datagrid

Comment: @vini : you can use the above code inside cancel button click event

Comment: my button is inside datagrid i dun think jquery can fetch the button click directly

Comment: <td class="style1">
                                                <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" class="vini" />
                                            </td>

Comment: how do i access this button present inside the datagrid

Comment: @vini:use class to access this button `$(.vini).click(function(){});`

Comment: i am not able to access the status when i am debugging using firebug

Comment: use `label` keyword like $(DataGrid1).find("label").html(); dont use 
`find("txtStatDesc")`